# how to set the input text in react by taking it from from the url?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to input a location as text input
I want qr code to show the blow and location is the dynamic input we put in the input field
[https://google.com?location={location}](https://google.com?location=%7Blocation%7D) ?

How can i set the url as above and put the location as input? showup in qr code

so input will be the location from the url which can be any location and the qr code should show <url/
currently i am using the below code but i can only get the input field showup in the qr code .

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import QRCode from 'qrcode.react';

function App() {

  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');
  const [qrCodeText, setQRCodeText] = useState('');

  // generate QR code
  const generateQRCode = () => {
    setQRCodeText(inputText);
  }

  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>Generate and download a QR code image in React Omneo</h3>
      <div className="qr-input">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter input"
          value={inputText}
          onChange={e => setInputText(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="Generate"
          onClick={generateQRCode}
        />
      </div>
      <QRCode
        id="qrCodeEl"
        size={150}
        value={qrCodeText}
      />
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//add to the top
import { useEffect } from 'react'

//add above return
useEffect(() => {
    setInputText(window.location.href);
  })
```

Comment: i already tried this where we get the url in the input but the problem is i want to take the location from the url and use it in input and show the url in qr @user1898662

Answer (score 0):

If the URL only has one parameter (location) you can split and get the rest. If there are more parameters you can split by '&' then location

```js
useEffect(() => {
    setInputText(window.location.href.split("location=")[1]);
}, [])
```

Comment: using useffect to set the url, i already tried but i get only the url that i pass but the problem is i want to take the location from the url and use it in input and show the url in qr @Raven

Comment: so input will be the location from the url which can be any location and the qr code should show <url/<the location input we give>

Comment: In theory this should work since when window.location.href changes it sets again but it doesnt work you you can also use useParam hook from react router
useEffect(() => {
   if(window.location.href.includes('location')
    setInputText(window.location.href.split("location=")[1]);
}, [window.location.href])